# Calling JS interops multiple times with Blazor

Tags: javascript, setinterval, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsinterop

My server-side Blazor app calls multiple times a javascript function that is supposed to move a div around (using setInterval).
The issue is that the function does not wait for the previous call to finish. As a result, the DOM is changed from different js interops at the same time which leads to unpredictable results. I was expecting the calls to be stacked up and run one by one.
Do you have an idea how can I solve this issue? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the only way is to use custom data attributes on the **DOM** as a lock.
Something like that: `data-lockincrement="0"`
Each JSInterop call should include that `lockincrement` so `Setinterval` continues until `lockincrement` matches the value which means the calls will be executed sequentially.